# creating a dictionary in Pandas using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary for the following dataset usin:

```
id  value
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   e
2   f
2   g
3   h
3   g
3   l
```

The output should be like this

```
{1: [a,b,c], 2:[e, f, g], 3: [h, g, l]}
```

I know some references on how create dictionary, but none of them give such an output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Groupby and form lists and then create a dictionary

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(list).to_dict()
# {1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g'], 3: ['h', 'g', 'l']}
```

Comment: Hi AlLollz, thank you. When I am trying on the dataframe I have, it has the following error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_dic'. I only have two columns in the dataframe.

Comment: @Mary it looks like you are missing a `t`? at the end of `to_dict`